# httpd cannot deliver files bigger that 255 bytes

Tags: httpd

I have fresh install of opensuse leap 15.1. Installed apache + php7 + mysql, everything from official repos. Enabled mod_php and mod_rewrite. On localhost everything seemt to work fine. Other devices cannot receive files bigger than (I think) 255 bytes (like css files). Php seems to work fine.
Firewall is configured to allow traffic on port 80.
There is no virtual hosts configured on httpd, only default one.
What can it be?

> 254 bytes file works fine
>   http://188.193.128.108/ea.css
>
> 264 bytes file problem: http://188.193.128.108/ea2.css

No errors in error_log. Nothing special in access_log, everything has status 200. curl -l shows also nothing special, content lenght > 0, status 200. wget downloads just empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved by adding

> EnableSendfile Off

into apache server config